# Prototype Access & Behavior

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

1.1: Why does accessing `x` directly on `linkingObject` not work but accessing it on `linkingObject.prototype` does?

1.2: Once `linkingObject` is searched for `x`, shouldn't the engine by default then search its prototype for `x`? Why do I need to explicitly state `.prototype`?

1.3: To further illustrate how weird this is, you can see that `baseObject` is the prototype of `linkingObject` and it even states that it contains the `x`property.

```
const baseObject = function() {};

baseObject.prototype.x = 5;

const linkingObject = Object.create(baseObject);

console.log(linkingObject.x); // 1.1: undefined
console.log(linkingObject.prototype.x); // 1.2: 5
console.log(linkingObject.prototype); // 1.3: baseObject { x:5 }
```

Comment: You're inheriting from a function object. Don't do that, it's just weird. You want `const baseObject = {x: 5}`, no `.prototype` properties (which are only relevant for constructors that are used with `new`).

Answer (score 0):

You have confused the `prototype` property of a function object with the first entry in an object's inheritance chain. The latter is often written as `[[prototype]]` because it it is an internal value referring to the start of the inheritance chain.

The [[prototype]] internal property (called a "slot") of an object is set to the `prototype` property of its constructor, or in the case of objects created by  `Object.create`, the object value supplied as first argument.

So you set the [[prototype]] value of `linkingObject` to the function `baseObject`. Searching `linkingObject` will find `prototype` in the inheritance chain (it's a property of `baseObject`) and then find `linkingObject.prototype.x` as a defined property of the inherited `prototype` value.

But `baseObject` the function does not have an `x` property itself, so searching for the non-existent `linkingObject.x` property returns `undefined`.